# MySQL (id >= N AND col2 IS NULL) query unexpectedly slow for large N

Tags: mysql, performance

We are using MySQL 5.5.42.

We have a table `publications` containing about 150 million rows (about 140 GB on an SSD).

The table has many columns, of which two are of particular interest:

- `id` is primary key of the table and is of type `bigint`
- `cluster_id` is a nullable column of type `bigint`

Both columns have their own (separate) index.

We make queries of the form

```
SELECT * FROM publications
WHERE id >= 14032924480302800156 AND cluster_id IS NULL
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 0, 200;
```

> **Here is the problem**: The larger the `id` value (14032924480302800156 in the example above), the slower the request.

In other words, requests for low `id` value are fast (< 0.1 s) but the higher the `id` value, the slower the request (up to minutes).

Everything is fine if we use another (indexed) column in the `WHERE` clause. For instance

```
SELECT * FROM publications
WHERE inserted_at >= '2014-06-20 19:30:25' AND cluster_id IS NULL
ORDER BY inserted_at
LIMIT 0, 200;
```

where `inserted_at` is of type `timestamp`.

Edit:

Output of `EXPLAIN` when using `id >= 14032924480302800156`:

```
id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys      | key        | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra
---+-------------+--------------+------+--------------------+------------+---------+-------+----------+------------
1  | SIMPLE      | publications | ref  | PRIMARY,cluster_id | cluster_id | 9       | const | 71647796 | Using where
```

Output of `EXPLAIN` when using `inserted_at >= '2014-06-20 19:30:25'`:

```
id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys          | key        | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra
---+-------------+--------------+------+------------------------+------------+---------+-------+----------+------------
1  | SIMPLE      | publications | ref  | inserted_at,cluster_id | cluster_id | 9       | const | 71647796 | Using where
```

Comment: Maybe for larger `id`s, it is more rare that `cluster_id` matches the requested value (`NULL`)? In that case for larger `id`s the database may need to traverse more records in order to select the requested 200 with `cluster_id IS NULL`.

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) for both using small and big id.

Comment: @SergeRogatch This is an excellent remark, and we thought about it, but I find it hard to believe that this would explain three-orders-of-magnitude slowdowns.

Comment: @ImreL I edited the question to add the output of EXPLAIN for both queries.

Comment: I'm just curious, why are you using BigInt instead of unsigned Int ? Is the ID column going to cross 4294967295 records ? If not, your selection of the datatype is not optimal.

Comment: @SJan Yes, as you can see in the example query above, most of our ids are way larger than 2^32-1.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune Indexing BigInt is slower than Timestamp (int value).

Comment: @SJan Sorry but you're completely missing the point of the question: we're witnessing 1000x slowdowns as we progress in our table with larger than larger ids. I don't see how this has anything to do with the fact that bigint are slower to index than int.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune I don't think I'm entirely missing the point. It's about indexing BigInt vs Int, the values range are different by two-orders-of-magnitude. That is the expected performance ! Maybe you can tune your DB by reducing the query cache size, and do some other tunings, but as far as your datatype and length of int are concerned that's the expected behavior (bigger the size, longer the processing time)

Comment: Does [using/forcing `PRIMARY` index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html) in your first request change processing times tremendously? If so, I might have a theory...

Comment: @SJan, First of all, we're talking about queries against indexes; this has nothing to do with indexing. Second, bigint is 64-bit while int is 32-bit. This is about 10 orders of (decimal) magnitude, not 2 (not that this has anything to do with the problem on hand). Third, please read again the question: we're observing curious performance characteristics in a very precise situation. Please refrain from commenting unless you understand the various aspects of that situation.

Comment: Just to check the (seemingly) obvious, this *is* an InnoDB table, right?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, absolutely!

Comment: Well, I'm pretty much stumped, then. +1 for a weird puzzle. :) Anyway, here's a few random shots in the dark you could try, just in case they might produce some helpful results: 1) Does `SELECT id` instead of `SELECT *` make any difference? 2) What about `ORDER BY cluster_id, id`? 3) Or dropping the `ORDER BY` entirely? 4) As D-side suggested above, what about `USE INDEX (PRIMARY)`? (It *should* be worse, but...) 5) Does changing the `>=` to `<=` make any difference? 6) What about dropping the `LIMIT` and just asking for the number of rows with `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen All good suggestions, will try that as soon as MySQL gives me back the hand, we're currently building a compound index... Will keep you posted, thanks!

Comment: My theory is that since indexes use primary key ordering for otherwise unordered sets (guesswork!), it may be using indexes in the wrong order: tossing `PRIMARY` away as a "last resort" measure. Therefore, it uses index on `cluster_id` and gets a large unindexed set of rows with `NULL`. Having no other choice it issues a linear scan on that set. That would mean that the optimizer failed horribly. In the latter case, two "non-special" indexes are used in the order specified, yielding expected performance.

Comment: @D-side @IlmariKaronen `USE INDEX(PRIMARY)` seems to solve the problem! So does selecting only `id`. I will investigate further.

Comment: @D-side @IlmariKaronen I suppose that asking only for `id` is very fast because we're only hitting the index. Dropping `ORDER BY` and/or `LIMIT` doesn't help. Asking for `COUNT(*)` (without `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT`) is also very slow.

Comment: @D-side If you post an answer suggesting to use `USE INDEX (PRIMARY)` I will gladly accept it!

Comment: BIGINT is 8 bytes; INT is 4 bytes.  This does not make much difference in indexing.  TIMESTAMP (in 5.5) is 4 bytes and stored effectively as an int, so it should perform identically to INT.

Comment: The Query cache size should be very much irrelevant to these queries.  If the QC were involved, the query would return in about 0.001s, not the bigger values quoted.

Comment: It is possible (but hard to prove in 5.5) that the SELECT used a different explain plan than the EXPLAIN shows.  I am struggling to explain what you are seeing.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune - No, asking for only `id` cannot be explained by hitting only the index -- the "index" is the InnoDB `PRIMARY KEY`, which is clustered with the data.  That is that "index" is the entire table.  The good thing is that its order matches the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Is `id` a `BIGINT`?  Or a `BIGINT UNSIGNED`?  I ask because your example is too big to store in a `BIGINT`, and may do nasty things when stuffed into it.

Comment: In particular:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72046

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some guesswork involved about MySQL using indexes in the wrong order. `PRIMARY` index seems to be treated in a completely different way than the others.

In a query with a primary key condition indexes `PRIMARY` and on `cluster_id` can be used. For some reason, MySQL ignored `PRIMARY` index and looks at an index on `cluster_id` first, where you have a condition: it should be `NULL`. That leaves us with a huge potentially unordered (`NULL`s everywhere!) set of rows to be filtered by `id`.

With the next query, however, it's different: `PRIMARY` index cannot be used at all, so MySQL figures what to use in a better way, apparently using an index on `inserted_at` first without any hints.

What it should actually do in first query is take `PRIMARY` index first ([tell it to do so](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html)). I am not a MySQL user, all my guesswork is backed only by my own understanding of internal data structures. I don't know whether it can apply an index on `cluster_id` on top of the results, but creating a composite index and comparing performance with and without it may give clues on whether it's used.

Comment: Thanks, adding `USE INDEX (PRIMARY)` solves the problem.

Comment: Do you think recomputing the table statistics help? (It's quite an undertaking given the size of the database...)

Comment: Well, if you've managed to make a better guess at what index to use than the program did -- it may be of no use trying to make it make better decisions. You've already got it working. However, figuring out "why" may lead to some improvement in MySQL itself.

Comment: The problem is that we are not really writing SQL queries by hand, they are generated by Entity Framework. Writing SQL queries by hand introduces a bunch of new problems that ideally we would like to avoid... Adding an index is also not an ideal solution due to the additional disk space it requires (in backups, etc.).

Comment: I'm not a MySQL user so I can't be of much assistance on its maintenance. Sorry :(

Comment: `ANALYZE TABLE` for an InnoDB table is very fast (and very sloppy).

Answer (score 0):

The performance issue is most likely happening because you only have separate indexes for columns `id` and `cluster_id`, but not an index on both these columns simultaneously.

Maybe for larger ids, it is more rare that cluster_id matches the requested value (NULL)? In that case for larger ids the database may need to traverse more records in order to select the requested 200 with `cluster_id IS NULL`.

If you had a single index on both columns, the database wouldn't need to traverse that many records because it would know which records satisfy the 2 search criteria simultaneously.

Comment: We thought about this, however this doesn't explain why performance are excellent when using `inserted_at` instead of `id` (we don't have an index on `inserted_at` and `cluster_id` simultaneously).

Comment: Do higher `inserted_at` correspond to higher `id`s? Unless you are using an SSD, a rotating hard disk can easily give several orders of magnitudes slowdown if accessed randomly with small blocks of data. Because rotating hard drives can perform 100-200 seek operations per second (which is the number of full rotations per second).

Comment: Yes, higher `inserted_at` values correspond to higher `id` values.

Comment: Maybe it's related to that fact that BigInt is 8Bytes and Timestamp is 4Bytes. Anyway, why are you using BigInt ? Are you going to have more than 4 billion records ?

Comment: @SergeRogatch Our database is stored on SSD on an Amazon instance.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune, what is the size of the database in bytes?

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune You said : "most of our ids are way larger than 2^32-1" However ''inserted_a'' are way  smaller than that. Timestamp counts the number of seconds since 1970, and current timestamp value is (~1437046346 seconds)

Comment: @SJan You're mixing things up. As I said, our *ids* are larger than 2^32-1.

Comment: @SergeRogatch The size of our database is approximately 600 GB.

Comment: This would be a plausible explanation, except that, AIUI, all InnoDB secondary indexes [implicitly contain the primary key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html) at the end. So, AFAIK, the `cluster_id` index should effectively act as a compound index on `(cluster_id, id)` already, and that's precisely the index that this kind of query *should* benefit from.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune, so even if SSD speed is 500MB/second, it would take 20 minutes to read the whole database. That is why your queries can easily take minutes, if indexes are not set up correctly to speed-up those queries. Although, as Ilmari Karonen mentioned, each secondary index contains the primary key (or clustered index?), I am not sure whether such entry of primary key/clustered index is usable for speeding up queries containing both primary key and something else. By the way, which columns are in the clustered index for your table?